# How can I conditionally add items to Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to conditionally add items to Firestore. In the example below, I want to only add `code`, `time` & `comment` if `add` is `true`.

```
await firebase
   .firestore()
   .collection("codes")
   .add({
      total,
      subtotal,
      code: add && code,
      time: add && new Date(),
      comment: add && comment
   });
```

Right now, if `add` is false `code`, `time` & `comment` gets appended to Firestore as boolean `false`. I want nothing to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
let obj = {}
obj.total = total;
obj.code  = codePresent?code : null;

Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => {
     obj[key] == null? delete obj[key] : key
});

console.log(obj);
```

Basically create an empty object, then add the keys with the values. Regarding the `code` field use a ternary operator if `codePresent` is false then assign it null. Then use `Object.key()` which will return an array of keys, then you can use the `filter()` method and delete the keys who's value is null from the object. In the end just pass the object as an argument to the `add()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your code with an `if` statement and check for `codePresent`s value:

```js
if(codePresent) { // or better - if(code) {...
  await firebase
   .firestore()
   .collection("codes")
   .add({
      total,
      code // this is the same as doing { code: code }
   });
}
```

if you have moultiple cases and you don't want to add a bunch of if statements, you can simply filter your variables based on their content:

```js
const payloadOptions = {
  foo: "some random data";
  code: "function foo() { return 'foo' }";
  empty: null;
  optionalParameter: null;
}


const filteredPayload = Object
// turning our object into an entry array, i.e [["foo", "some random data"..]]
                             .entries(payloadOptions) 
// if we have a value, we assign it to our accumulator
                             .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
                               if(value) { 
                                 acc[key] = value;
                               }
                             }, {});

await firebase
   .firestore()
   .collection("codes")
   .add(filteredPayload);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only reason I'm asking is I actually have many fields that I want to conditionally add. I only showed one example for simplicity. I just don't want to have a bunch of `if` statements.

Comment: @devon66h - I've updated my comment, could you please edit your question to be more clear?